# How do I output the row containing the lowest value from a specific column inside a filtered dynamic array?

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays, filterfunction

I have a list of suppliers which contains the product name and the prices. I then formatted the data where there are multiple entries of the product name but under different suppliers. For each product, I need the lowest price and under what supplier I can get that lowest price from.

I don't know if there's an easier method through power query but the solution I used is using `FILTER`.

```
=FILTER(DATA,CRITERIA)
```

| ITEM | SUPPLIER | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITEMA | SUPPLIERA | 100 |
| ITEMA | SUPPLIERB | 150 |
| ITEMA | SUPPLIERC | 125 |
| ITEMB | SUPPLIERA | 100 |
| ITEMB | SUPPLIERB | 150 |
| ITEMB | SUPPLIERC | 125 |

What I tried:
I was able to create a FILTER function to output the suppliers and price based on the item I need. Through searching the net, I don't know how to get the minimum number from the filtered list itself.

Output I was able to get through the function:
UNIQUE(TABLE[ITEM])|FILTER(TABLE,A1=TABLE[ITEM])

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITEMA | SUPPLIERA | 100 |
| ITEMA | SUPPLIERB | 150 |
| ITEMA | SUPPLIERC | 125 |

Since the output is a dynamic array, I don't know how to "read" the 3rd column of this array to get the minimum value.

Comment: I would be looking at index() and match(), lots of examples on here

Comment: You mean an inline INDEX-MATCH? Cause I'm able to get the minimum using the filter output through LOOKUPs and MIN. I just don't know how to add it to my FILTER function so that everything can be solved in a single cell

Comment: To put it in a single cell, do some research on the `LET` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Instead of using 1 filter function to output the whole row, I used 2 filter functions.

First filter function gets the minimum value with the selected criteria:
`MIN(FILTER(TABLE[PRICE],A1=ITEMA))`

Second filter function outputs the row with the minimum value:
`FILTER(TABLE,B1=TABLE[PRICE])`

So my dynamic table looks like
|A|B|C|
|-|-|-|
|ItemA|=MIN(FILTER(TABLE[PRICE],A1=ITEMA))|=FILTER(TABLE,B1=TABLE[PRICE])|

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ItemA | 100 | SupplierB | 100 |

For clarity sake, I decided to leave the extra 100 there but there is a way to output filter only specific columns and that's what I used